# python PIL installation on python 3.6

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I have tried to install PIL, however unsuccessfully.
I used the commands:

```
pip install pillow

sudo pip3 install pillow
```

And yet python didn't recognize PIL.
Any solutions to this problem ?

Comment: Please show some code that caused the error and the error you see.

Answer (score 1):

You might be having PIL already installed which may be conflicting. Go to your python packages and manually delete pillow, Pillow, PIL etc and reinstall using `pip install pillow`

Comment: Doesn't seem to help :/

Comment: It says the module doesn't exist even though it does.

Comment: from PIL import Image . You need to import that

Comment: It still doesn't recognize it. It worked once but later failed to recognize PIL or Image

Answer (score 1):

You say that it worked once and then later does not. A mistake that I have made more than once is naming a script that I am writing pil.py, and then wondering why I can't import PIL. So that could be an explanation.

If the installation is truly the problem though, here are some alternatives.

You could try python3.6 -m pip install Pillow - it does the same thing, but you never know.

You could try downloading the source code of Pillow - https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/releases - and running python3.6 setup.py install to install it directly. This will likely fail to lack of other requirements, but again, just giving ideas.

If you're on Linux, you could try your relevant package manger - apt install python3-pil for Ubuntu, etc.